# Understanding OpenId Connect client_credentials grant in terms of identity

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have trouble understanding the client_credentials grant in terms of identity. I have secured my web app with OpenId Connect using the authorization code flow. This works as expected and a proper access and id token are returned from the authorization server. So far so good.

Now i have some public APIs i want to give my customers access to. The access to this APIs is done via our different client libraries that we provide.

In many examples out there the `client_credentials` flow is used for that providing a **CLIENT_ID** and a **CLIENT_SECRET** to get an access token. According to the spec this flow involves no end user and therfore no identity token is returned.

Now i am in trouble because i don't know the identity of the caller. The only thing i can say is that the access token is valid but how is this done in practice ?

How do you know which user called your service when using this flow ? Do i have to save a mapping from user_account to client_id/client secret and query for that in my api endpoint to get the user ? I have to make some access decissions based on the identity who called the service.

If that would be true what benefit does OpendId Connect provide for me in that manner when i can get no id token in that flow ? Doing this with simple Oauth2 client_credentials flow will lead to the same result.

Can someone give me some tipps ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `client_credentials` flow is not meant to be used in scenario's where you want to identify an end user. In fact the `client_credentials` grant type is undefined in OpenID Connect. You should rely on the Authorization Code grant as you suggest.

Comment: But does that mean my customers can never access my APIs without interacting with the user agent before ?

Comment: @Jay you don't need OpenID Connect for interactions between a client and an API. OAuth2 is enough in this case.

Comment: And how do i know WHO is calling my API? For example which customer when i don't have any kind of identity information ?

Comment: as said, when you want to identify an end user (reliably), you cannot use `client_credentials`